# How to remove page from the Navigation list and also terminate all the process for that page?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In one of the scenarios, I need to navigate back from the existing page and along with that, I want to ensure that all of the running processes for that page is terminated.

With Navigation `PopAsync` and `RemovePage` methods, it's simply removing page but not terminating any of the processes. I know that `CancellationToken` can be useful but am not sure which process the user is running right now and I don't think writing CancellationToken on every button should be a good approach.

Is there any solution where I can navigate back and terminate all the running processes of that page?

Suppose that I have 15 buttons doing some task and for example let's consider below code:

```
     async void Button1_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
      {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Count:" + i);
                }
      }
    
    async void Button2_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
      {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Count:" + i);
                }
      }
    
     async void Button3_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
      {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Count:" + i);
                }
      }
```

and so on...

Now, in the above example, Whenever the user will click any button it will start printing count and now once user is navigating back to the previous page still it's printing the count. How can we avoid such a situation and stop all the processes?

Answer (score 0):

When calling `PopAsync` and `RemovePage` methods, there is a `OnDisappearing` method where  can be used to close all the processes of that page.

```
public partial class PageMain : ContentPage
{
    public PageMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        // Destroying threads
        Thread.Abort
    }
}
```

However, the processes need to be managed manually from it be created to be destroyed. More **[Destroying threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/destroying-threads)** info can refer to this document.

==================================Update===================================

From shared sample code, here is the sample how to cancel `Task`:

```
async void Button1_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    tokenSource1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken ct = tokenSource1.Token;
    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Were we already canceled?
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        bool moreToDo = true;
        while (moreToDo)
        {
            // Poll on this property if you have to do
            // other cleanup before throwing.
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // Clean up here, then...
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
        }
    }, tokenSource1.Token); // Pass same token to Task.Run.
      
}

...

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();

    tokenSource1.Cancel();
    tokenSource2.Cancel();
    tokenSource3.Cancel();

}
```

Above code is using **[CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation)** to cancel the `Task`s manually.

Also can refer to **[Cancel a list of tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/cancel-an-async-task-or-a-list-of-tasks)** to cancel them more smarter.

Comment: Thanks, but I have many methods inside my page and there might be multiple threads running at a time. I am not sure which threads are in process, so how can I abort all the running threads? Also, some might just an event execution that is not withing any thread.

Comment: @Dishant Okey, you can share some sample code in question, I will check how to abort them.

Comment: I have updated my question with the example. Please do have a look. Thank you.

Comment: @Dishant Thanks for updating question. Based on `Task`, I will update answer. When you have time can have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. As I mentioned in my question, I don't want to go with the CancellationTokenSource route as that will bloat the code on each and every function which is a very bad design. Is there any simple solution to this?

Comment: @Dishant Okey, I'm afraid that there isn't a simple way to manange the `Task` in Xamarin.